# Animate multiple <DIV> elements on page load and page unload

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs, animate.css

I am using the Animate.CSS plugin to provide animation to my `div` elements during loading of a page. Basically, I have a number of elements that I slideIn as the page displays.

I want to create the effect for the same elements to slideOut as the page closes and the next page opens. Please note that I do not use the click event to move to a new page - it automatically moves through a list of angular-ui-routes.

I currently call my animation by calling `<div class="animated fadeInLeft">`

Answer (score 0):

If you are using `ui-router` then use below plugin. it was amazing.

[angular-ui-router-anim-in-out](https://github.com/homerjam/angular-ui-router-anim-in-out)

**EDIT**

```
  <div ui-view="container" autoscroll="false"  class="anim-in-out anim-fade" data-anim-speed="500" data-anim-sync="false"></div>
```

Comment: Far out, there is an angular model for everything.  I will check it out and get back to you soon.  Thankyou

Comment: Do you know how I can specify between `anim-in` and `anim-out` for my elements?  It only shows setting an animation type on each element.

Comment: Whilst I seem to have this working, I notice that the during the page transition (anim-out), the contents of the page are shifted to the bottom before they slide out.  Even though it's for a split second, it still creates a bit of an ugly affect.

Comment: Also, the `data-anim-speed` doesn't seem to be adjusting anything.